Show that $\sum_n \frac{z^{2^n}}{1-z^{2^{n+1}}} $ converges when $z^{2} \ne 1$
Proble Let $z$ complex number such that $z^{2} \ne 1$. Show that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{2^n}}{1-z^{2^{n+1}}}$ converges.
I already know that questions have been asked about similar problems before, but in most of them the condition for $z$ was $|z|<1$. Here's what I've come up with so far.
$\forall \ n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}, \frac{z^{2^{n}}}{1-z^{2^{n+1}}} = \frac{z^{2^{n}}+z^{2^{n+1}}}{1-z^{2^{n+1}}}-\frac{z^{2^{n+1}}}{1-z^{2^{n+1}}}=
\frac{z^{2^{n}}\left(1+z^{2^{n}} \right)}{\left(1-z^{2^{n}}\right)\left(1+z^{2^{n}}\right)}
-\frac{z^{2^{n+1}}}{1-z^{2^{n+1}}}=
\frac{z^{2^{n}}}{1-z^{2^{n}}}-\frac{z^{2^{n+1}}}{1-z^{2^{n+1}}}$
Let $s_{n} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{z^{2^k}}{1-z^{2^{k+1}}}$. Then by telescoping, $s_{n}
=\frac{z}{1-z} - -\frac{z^{2^{n+1}}}{1-z^{2^{n+1}}}$.
I'm not sure how to use the condition $z^{2} \ne 1$ at this later stage, although I've substituted a few examples (e.g. $z = i$) and the series seems to converge. Even a small hint would be appreciated.

Hint
You're a fraction of a millimetre from the finishing line.  Hopefully the following identity should push you over it.
$$
\frac{z^{2^{n+1}}}{1-z^{2^{n+1}}}=\frac{1}{1-z^{2^{n+1}}}-1\ .
$$
However, what you've nearly shown is that the proposition you're trying to prove is false as stated. I believe you need $\ |z|\ne1\ ,$ not merely $\ z^2\ne1\ .$ In fact, if $\ z=e^\frac{i\pi}{2^{k-1}}\ ,$ then the quantity $\ \frac{z^{2^n}}{1-z^{2^{n+1}}}\ $ isn't even defined for $\ n\ge k-1\ $

Hint:
If $\vert z\vert > 1,$ then $\exists\ N$ such that $ \displaystyle\left\lvert \frac{z^{2^n}}{1-z^{2^{n+1}}}\right\rvert < \frac{\left\lvert z^{2^n}\right\rvert}{\frac{1}{2}\left\lvert z^{2^n}z^2\right\rvert}\quad \forall\ n\geq N. $
If $\vert z\vert < 1,$ then $\exists\ N$ such that $ \displaystyle \left\lvert \frac{z^{2^n}}{1-z^{2^{n+1}}}\right\rvert<\left\lvert \frac{z^{2^n}}{1/2}\right\rvert\quad \forall\ n\geq N. $
